# Including Flash content inline in a custom Weblog?

Tags: python, django, flash, blogs

I'm trying to think of a way to place Flash content into a blog post so that it appears inline between paragraphs. I'm writing a custom weblog application in Django (still learning) and I'll be using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for the embedding.

The blog is for me only so the back-end isn't too fancy. I'm simply using Django's built in admin interface. No TinyMCE rich text editor (like Wordpress), rather I've implemented [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/).

I'd like to add Flash content into the body of a post, between paragraphs, in a way that is not coupled to any third party script. Meaning, I would prefer not to include javascript within the body of the blog post as it introduces a dependency on SWFObject. For example, I could quite easily add the following to an entry via the back-end to embed a SWF inline:

```
Paragraph one...

<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("/path/to/flash.swf", "myContent", "200", "200", "9.0.0");
</script>
<div id="myContent"></div>

Paragraph two...
```

As you can see this is quite wordy and a lot to remember but it also refers to SWFObject directly. This WILL work, however I would prefer to write it in a "cleaner" more abstract way. What I was thinking of doing is creating my own parser which would translate a custom string into the above just before rendering a template.

```
[#SWF swf="/path/to/flash.swf" w="200" h="200" ver="9.0.0"]
```

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this issue. I'd love to know how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into OEmbed, specifically the [django-oembed](http://code.google.com/p/django-oembed/) project.